# Analog magazine story fm late 70s. Computer w/ voice recognition wakes guy up, reads news, makes coffee etc

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It has been around 40 years since I read the story, so the details are a little vague.  Best guess is it was published after Star Wars was released in 1977 and probably before 1980.

From my recollection, the author basically described virtual assistants like Siri/Alexa and something akin to the WWW.

The story started with the human asleep, and the computer woke him up, read him the important news, maybe some messages, and did some other stuff like maybe setting the thermostat and making coffee.  Sort of a "day in the life with a virtual assistant."

Comment: There was no plot, just a "slice of life"? Was the human male or female? Any particular geographical setting? How futuristic was the story, e.g., was the news about interplanetary/interstellar affairs?

Comment: I'm almost sure the human was male.  It was set in near-future earth.  I don't recall any space component, but there may have been a touch of "Cousin George is working on the Moon this week."

Comment: Browsed through my 70s Analogs. Found a story (The Man Who Drove to Work) *vaguely* reminiscent of your description  but not it. Lots of automation: "Servo-arms came from the ceiling to clear the table", "Two vacuum cleaners the size of cats scurried from his path as they sensed his body heat." But it begins with the guy finishing breakfast. It's the day the main character, who has been working from home as a division chief of a food company, gets promoted to Vice President, so he gets to get out of his house and drive to the chicken plant with a lunch bucket and tools and work with his hands.

Comment: Hmm.  It's possible the story could have been published as early as 1974.  The interesting theme of the piece was that this miraculous technology would be used by regular folks, not just Captain Kirk and Darth Vader.